# Get the difference time between two NSString in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate

I have two strings coming from my server in which I store the time, and I need to compare the time interval between those two, in minutes, and if it's necessary, in hours. Should I convert to `NSDate` or use `NSString`?

The `NSString`s look like:

```
NOW 14:22
LAST TIME 10:18
```

EDIT #1
Since everyone is saying me to use NSDate, i converted the data in my database to DATETIME, and now i can compare the two NSDate using the following code :

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"pt_BR"]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

    NSDate *currentDateTimeWithOffset = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:[[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] secondsFromGMT]];

    NSString *strDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDateTimeWithOffset];
    NSDate * now = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strDate];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2013-04-09 12:10:18"];

NSLog(@"Difference %f",[now timeIntervalSinceDate:date]);
```

And the result is the following :

```
 Difference 864.000000
 NOW 2013-04-09 15:24:42 +0000
 LAST DATE 2013-04-09 12:10:18
```

Is that correct? the Difference is in Seconds?

Comment: You have about 5 different options.  Simplest is to crack the format yourself.  Or you can use NSDateFormatter, with or without NSCalendar.  And someone probably will come up with a regular expression version if you wait long enough.  If you use NSDateFormatter/NSCalendar, beware of timezone gotchas.

Answer (score 5):

If the format gets more complex than the one you've shown, consider using NSDateFormatter.  For the simple example:

```
NSArray *hoursMins = [timeString componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
NSInteger timeInMins = [hoursMins[0] intValue] * 60 + [hoursMins[1] intValue];
```

Then subtract the two times in minutes.  The date formatter approach looks like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:timeString];
```

You can get a difference in seconds between two dates using:

```
[date timerIntervalSinceDate:anotherDate];
```

Comment: Won't the values in the hourMins array be strings?  You're doing math on the values in the calculation.

Comment: +1 for NSDateFormatter example, which is the method I would use.

Comment: Thanks @danh i think your solution almost get me there, edited the question for better understanding

Comment: But remember that any NSDateFormatter solution should beware of timezone and locale gotchas.

Comment: @darkman, I think the best practice is to store dates in UTC, and to the extent possible, do date math / comparison all in UTC.  Then use timezone only as a user-friendly way to present dates to a person a particular locale.

Answer (score 0):

NSDateFormatter is the "clean" way to do it. But if you are looking for quick and dirty, and those are the actual strings you are getting (that include the NOW and LAST TIME), I'd just use a specific NSRange to pull the hours and minutes out and compare them.

Make sure, though that you check the hours, and if the "now" hour is before the "last time" hour, you add 24 to the now to throw in the day rollover.

Answer (score -1):

With only `NSString`, [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html) is used to get [NSDate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
NSDateFormatter *rfc3339DateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];

[rfc3339DateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
[rfc3339DateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"];
[rfc3339DateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

// Convert the RFC 3339 date time string to an NSDate.
NSDate *date = [rfc3339DateFormatter dateFromString:rfc3339DateTimeString];
```

If you had separate values for hours, minutes and seconds you could use [NSCalendar](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html)

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setYear:1965];
[comps setMonth:1];
[comps setDay:6];
[comps setHour:14];
[comps setMinute:10];
[comps setSecond:0];
NSDate *date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps];
[comps release];
```

And a perfect solution would be to use timestamps instead of NSString. Not only it's easy to convert timestamps to `NSDate` (`NSDate +dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate`)and then to `NSString` when needed, but you can also get the time difference by subtraction.

And with two `NSDate` objects the time difference is calculated with `NSDate -timeIntervalSinceDate`.

Comment: This answer does not address the actual problem in the question.

Comment: @rmaddy It's not copy&paste solution which I'm not going to give for this level of the question anyway. And yes it does, both for the question before and after edit.